# Creating a subdomain (sub.domain.com) for special posts on a blog: Good idea?

Tags: seo, blog, links

I have created a few plugins and themes that I want to have special pages for. Now I do not want to make a complete new website or page for all the different plugins.

Instead I want to have normal blogposts for each of my plugins and themes. Now to make things more simple I want to create a special domain name for them, with CNAME records. like this:

facyplugin.mydomain.com  CNAME  mydomain.com/2011/09/new-fancy-plugin

Now instead of giving people the long version of the link, I can just give the small one, without having to use a url crusher.

--

Now is this a good idea, or will this lead to problems in terms of SEO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will have no effect on your SEO. [Subdomains are no different then subdirectories as far as SEO goes](http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/subdomains-and-subdirectories/). If you think this will make it easier to promote your plug-ins then definitely do it. But don't expect any special rankings because of it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, and I was not really looking for rankings, it was just to make things a little easier. Nice article also, I will read trough that.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like they're playing around with this during recent algorithm changes. The 'party line', as expressed in the Cutts' blog post, is that there is no difference between subdomains and subfolders. However, it can be observed that on some specific domains, such as WordPress.com and Google's own Blogger, there are differences in the way subdomains are treated. They seem to be treated in these special cases more like individual domains than sub-domains. HubPages was also convinced, apparently by Google, that their path back from Panda Update decimation was to move toward sub-domains. So, they seem like they're making some changes/tweaks but keeping quite about them to prevent excessive gaming of them.

For your average website though, it won't make any difference positive or negative. In your specific case, make sure your internal and external linking is consistent and use canonical tags to indicate the page URLs you want Google to index. You can also do this from Google Webmaster tools.

Answer (score -3):

I will suggest you to create sub directory and install blog on it , if you install the blog on sub doamin it will effect your seo absolutely so i will sugegst you to go for sub directory.

Comment: This isn't even close to being true